# Most cost effective cloud hosted database and app service?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a Xamarin mobile app that requires a central cloud data storage (so a database). I also need an app service to host an API to interface with the database. I have been leaning towards Azure for both of these needs to keep everything in the Microsoft/Azure space and I am also familiar with it, but I am not sure if that would be overkill for my needs.

The data I need to store is only a few hundred records across a couple of tables and does not contain sensitive information. The app service would be quite small. I used their cost calculator with the cheapest options and that came out to only about $7/month for a small database and they have a Free Tier for the app service, although I have read that it is very slow, not sure to what extent though for the simple use case I have for it. This is very reasonable unless I have to upgrade to the Basic Tier App Service which jumps up to $70/month, that becomes a bit more than what I am looking to spend for this.

Wondering if folks know if the Free Tier of the Azure App Service would be impractically slow to host an API. It is listed as using Shared Cores, 1 GB RAM, and 1GB of storage. Also open to suggestions for other options that play well with .NET. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, tool/product/service recommendation questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow: there's simply no way to answer this objectively, and there's no possible way to know if a particular service tier will work with your app without empirical performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

I run several web services between AWS and Azure. Depending on how you are planning to write your App Service you can go with Azure VM Standard B1s and they will fall under FREE tier usage. Else around $10 per month.

You can run an embedded DB like SQL Lite with ASP.net. I use Spring Boot and works well.

Comment: The question itself is off-topic (tool/product/service recommendation). Please don't answer questions like this, as there's simply no objective way to answer, and often leads to spam. Further, there's no possible way to know what offerings will be usable by the OP without proper testing.